# UnexpectedValueException: Could not parse version constraint >=~2: Invalid version string "~2"

Tags: yii2, composer-php

I'd tried:

1. composer global update
2. composer selfupdate
3. composer update

I got error at 3rd step.

I run php 7. Building a webpage use Yii2.
I had run "composer update" successfully in the past (as I remember, that is before updating php to 7)

Below is my composer.json

```
{
    "name": "yiisoft/yii2-app-basic",
    "description": "Yii 2 Basic Project Template",
    "keywords": ["yii2", "framework", "basic", "project template"],
    "homepage": "http://www.yiiframework.com/",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "BSD-3-Clause",
    "support": {
        "issues": "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues?state=open",
        "forum": "http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/",
        "wiki": "http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/",
        "irc": "irc://irc.freenode.net/yii",
        "source": "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "yiisoft/yii2": "*",
        "yiisoft/yii2-authclient": "*",
        "yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap": "*",
        "yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer": "*",
        "kartik-v/yii2-widget-datetimepicker": "*",
        "kartik-v/yii2-widget-select2": "@dev",
        "dektrium/yii2-user": "*",
        "philippfrenzel/yii2fullcalendar": "*",
        "kartik-v/yii2-widget-timepicker": "*",
        "kartik-v/yii2-widget-depdrop": "@dev",
        "wbraganca/yii2-dynamicform": "*",
        "kartik-v/yii2-widgets": "*",
        "kartik-v/yii2-grid": "@dev",
        "kartik-v/yii2-mpdf": "dev-master",
        "kartik-v/yii2-popover-x": "*",
        "kartik-v/yii2-krajee-base": "dev-master",
        "bluezed/yii2-scroll-top": "*",
        "kartik-v/yii2-icons": "@dev",
        "kartik-v/yii2-export": "*",
        "kartik-v/yii2-field-range": "*",
        "kartik-v/yii2-widget-typeahead": "*",
        "fxp/composer-asset-plugin": "*",
        "ext-gd": "*",
        "codemix/yii2-streamlog": "^1.0",
        "ext-intl": "*",
        "yii2mod/yii2-google-maps-markers": "*",
        "kartik-v/yii2-tabs-x": "*",
        "kartik-v/yii2-editable": "*",
        "kartik-v/yii2-money": "dev-master",
        "yiisoft/yii2-imagine": "*",
        "himiklab/yii2-recaptcha-widget": "*",
        "aws/aws-sdk-php": "^3.20",
        "aws/aws-php-sns-message-validator": "^1.1",
        "doctrine/cache": "^1.6",
        "fedemotta/yii2-aws-sdk": "*",
        "loveorigami/yii2-notification-wrapper": "*",
        "bower-asset/noty": "^2.3",
        "bower-asset/jquery-growl": "^1.3"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "yiisoft/yii2-codeception": "*",
        "yiisoft/yii2-debug": "*",
        "yiisoft/yii2-gii": "*",
        "yiisoft/yii2-faker": "*"
    },
    "config": {
        "process-timeout": 1800
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "yii\\composer\\Installer::postCreateProject"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "yii\\composer\\Installer::postCreateProject": {
            "setPermission": [
                {
                    "runtime": "0777",
                    "web/assets": "0777",
                    "yii": "0755"
                }
            ],
            "generateCookieValidationKey": [
                "config/web.php"
            ]
        },
        "asset-installer-paths": {
            "npm-asset-library": "vendor/npm",
            "bower-asset-library": "vendor/bower"
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: I don't see any package here with the version that could give error like this. `yiisoft/yii2-codeception` is deprecated so you should remove it from here but I'm not sure if this is the reason. Anyway try it.

Comment: I tried but still same error. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Exist a error with `"philippfrenzel/yii2fullcalendar": "*"` 
You can check this error with `composer update -vvv`

You can see here: https://github.com/philippfrenzel/yii2fullcalendar/issues/76

Use this to resolve temporaly:

```
$ composer global require fxp/composer-asset-plugin:~1.3@dev
```

After this if you obtain another error when you try to execute composer similar to this:

```
Changed current directory to /Users/xxxx/.composer

Fatal error: Call to undefined method Composer\Package\RootPackage::getConfig() in /Users/xxxx/.composer/vendor/fxp/composer-asset-plugin/Util/Config.php on line 125
```

To fixed this you only remove the folder:  `sudo rm -rf /Users/xxxx/.composer`